# How to update label in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvm, label

Beginner here.

I'm trying to get the exact time, when this operation was executed successfully and print it on label. The problem is that when I click the button, the label doesn't update the text.

```cs
namespace HGB.Droid.Helpers
{
    public class CallServiceHelper : ICallServiceHelper
    {
        IContactsHelper contactsHelper = DependencyService.Get<IContactsHelper>();
        List<Repository> ObjContactList = new List<Repository>();

        LabelModel labelModel = new LabelModel();

        Context context = Android.App.Application.Context;
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        public async Task UpdatePhonebook()
        {
            if (NetworkCheck.IsInternet())
            {
                var response = await client.GetAsync("http://mmmmmmmmmmm.aspx");
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string contactsJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Repository>>(contactsJson);

                    contactsHelper.DeleteContact();
                    ObjContactList = list;
                    foreach (Repository obj in ObjContactList)
                    {
                        contactsHelper.CreateContacts(obj.name, obj.phone);
                    }
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        labelModel.UpdateLabelValue.Execute(DateTime.Now.ToString());
                    });
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(context, "Error", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                });
                
            }
        }
```

I'm calling this function on UI button

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    ICallServiceHelper callServiceHelper = DependencyService.Get<ICallServiceHelper>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void updateContactsBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await callServiceHelper.UpdatePhonebook();
    }
}
```

This is my ViewModel

```
 public class LabelModel : BindableObject
{
    string dateValue = "Date Value";

    public LabelModel()
    {
        UpdateLabelValue = new Command<string>(UpdateLabel);
    }

    public ICommand UpdateLabelValue { get; }

    public string DateDisplay
    {
        get => dateValue;
        set
        {
            dateValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DateDisplay));
        }
    }

    void UpdateLabel(string newLabel)
    {
        DateDisplay = newLabel;
    }
}
```

And this is my Xaml file

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HGB.ViewModel"
         x:Class="HGB.MainPage">

<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:LabelModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Spacing="10">
    <Button
        Text="Update Phonebook"
        x:Name="updateContactsBtn"
        Clicked="updateContactsBtn_Clicked"
        />
    <Label
        VerticalOptions="Center"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        Text="{Binding DateDisplay}"
        />
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: `CallServiceHelper` creates a new instance of `LabelModel`.  Updating that model will not change the model that the page is referencing.

Comment: To add to Jason's comment: `LabelModel labelModel = new LabelModel();` is one instance of `LabelModel`. `<ContentPage.BindingContext><local:LabelModel/>` creates a DIFFERENT INSTANCE.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Should I delete <ContentPage.BindingContext><local:LabelModel/> from Xaml page and set BindingContext somewhere in code ?

Comment: Maybe. OR add to `IContactsHelper` a method `void SetLabelModel(LabelModel model);`, implement that in `CallServiceHelper`, then in MainPage constructor, after `InitializeContext();`, do `callServiceHelper.SetLabelModel((LabelModel)BindingContext);`

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Should I put something in void SetLabelModel(LabelModel model); method or just leave it blank ?

Comment: why does your Helper class need access to the VM?  Why not call the Helper method from the VM and have the helper return the string, then the VM can update itself with the string?

Comment: I'm using the Helper method in my Foreground Service class, where it gets called every 24 hours. What I'm trying to achieve is print the exact time, when the phonebook was successfully updated and print that date to my label.

Comment: use MessagingCenter to send a message from the Helper to your VM when the time is updated

Comment: @ArnasTranza - SetLabelModel should do what its name suggests:  `this.labelModel = model;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm using the Helper method in my Foreground Service class, where it
> gets called every 24 hours. What I'm trying to achieve is print the
> exact time, when the phonebook was successfully updated and print that
> date to my label.

For your problem, a simple method is to use  [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) just as Jason mentioned.

You can send message in your `CallServiceHelper`  and subscribe to this message in your ViewModel(`LabelModel.cs`).

Please refer to the following code:

1.In the constructor of your ViewMode(`LabelModel.cs`),subscribe to this message:

```
   public LabelModel()
    {
     MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, string>(this, "time", (sender, args) =>
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("received time is: "+ args);

        DateDisplay  = args;
    });
    }
```

2.In your `CallServiceHelper` , public your message:

```
MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, "time", "2022-4-8");
```